# when I scroll down the listview items are marked below the list

Tags: android, listview

I created a listview, which show that he marked this call: view.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.active_row) 
But when you scroll down the list, it marks items items that were below lista.exe: 
10 items are shown on the screen, marked the first when roll down the list so that it shows the 11, it marks this 11 item as if it were the first:

```
    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    SongsManager plm = new SongsManager();
    // get all songs from sdcard
    this.songsList = plm.getPlayList();
    // looping through playlist
    for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsListData.add(song);
    }
    // Adding menuItems to ListView
     final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData,
            R.layout.playlist_item, new String[] { "songTitle" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.songTitle2 });
    setListAdapter(adapter);

ListView lv = getListView();
    // listening to single listitem click
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        int flag1 = 0;
        int flag2 = 0;

        int auxPosicao1 = -1;//primeira vez
        int auxPosicao2 = -1;//primeira vez

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            View lastRow = null;        
            if (lastRow != null) {
                lastRow.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
                }
            if (flag1==0 &&((auxPosicao1 == position || (auxPosicao1 == -1 && auxPosicao2==-1)))){
                flag1 = 1;
                auxPosicao1 = position;
                aux = position;
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.active_row);

            }else if(auxPosicao1==position)
            {           
                if (flag2 == 1){

                    aux = aux2;
                    auxPosicao1 = auxPosicao2;  

                    aux2 = -1;
                    flag2 =0;
                    auxPosicao2 =-1;

                }else{
                    aux = -1;
                    flag1=0;
                    auxPosicao1 =-1;

                }
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.active_row2);

            }else if(flag2 == 0 &&((auxPosicao2 == position || auxPosicao2 == -1))){
                aux2 = position;
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.active_row);
                flag2 = 1;
                auxPosicao2 = position;

            }else if(position == auxPosicao2){
                aux2 = -1;
                flag2 =0;
                auxPosicao2 =-1;
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.active_row2);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Coming soon ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            //lastRow = view;
        }
    });
```

...
I need it to properly store the state of my list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android listview re-uses the same views

so once when you set the background color for one position

you need to reset the background color to back for other positions

Comment: can you give me an example of how to do this ?

Comment: post your listadapter class